# OpenCV not not able to find OpenCL on running the built exe in another environment

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, visual-studio-2012, opencl

I am running a sample code of opencv (ocl sample for people detection) in visual studio. When I run the code from this IDE (Ctrl+F5), I get the desired result.

But, When I copy the .exe generated by building the code and run it in another system, I get the following error: 
(In another system, I have also copied the required dll to the location where .exe is located)

OpenCV Error:Unknown error code -6 <
OpenCL function is not available: [clGet PlatformIDs]>

The settings of visual studio for the project are: 
The configuration type is :Application .exe 
Runtime Library: Multi-threaded Debug Dll(/MDd)

A similar question has been posted already but unanswered. It will be of great if anybody has some solutions.

Thank You!!

Comment: copy and paste the opencv & openCL (if there are any) Libraries into the exe folder

Comment: I did that. and still get the same error..

Comment: Did you try to build Release?